# Nested join with different separator

Tags: css, list, join, sass, nested-lists

I have two lists separated by space: `foo bar` and `baz ban`, embedded in a list: `(foo bar, baz ban)`. I want to join the two list by a comma, maintaining the space separator inside the list inside to get:

```
foo bar, baz ban
```

How can I do this?

When I do not specify the separator in `join` function, all gets joined by a space:

```
@debug join(foo bar, baz ban);
=> DEBUG: foo bar baz ban
```

When I specify `comma` for the separator in the `join` function, all separator becomes a space:

```
@debug join(foo bar, baz ban, comma);
=> DEBUG: foo, bar, baz, ban
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join()` will append one list to the other ... which means that from two one-dimensional lists, with two elements each, it will always make a one-dimensional list with four elements (as you already noticed).

To combine the two lists into a two-dimensional (nested) list with two elements (each being one of your original lists), you should just do something like this:

```
@debug (foo bar, baz ban);
=> DEBUG: foo bar, baz ban
```

#### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9032630)